# Embedding of algebras over global fields and local fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a global field, $A,B$ be two finite dimensional $K$ algebras. My question is, if $A \otimes_K K_v$ can be embedded in $B \otimes_K K_v$ for all places of $K$, can $A$ be embedded in $B$?[Here](https://math.mit.edu/~drew/AGCT2017.pdf) shows the answer is negative. But is it true if $B$ is a central simple algebra over $K$?

Motivation: by density theorem, the result is true for Galois field extensions of $K$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is $M_2(K)$ and $B$ is a quaternion algebra over $K$, then $A \otimes_K K_v$ embeds in $B \otimes_K K_v$ for all but finitely many places of $K$, but certainly $A$ does not embed in $B$.

Comment: Thank you, I see the assumption is too board and will edit it.

Comment: @zzy Wouldn't the existence of non-isomorphic arithmetically equivalent fields provide a counter-example?

Comment: I found https://math.mit.edu/~drew/AGCT2017.pdf helps, where the notion of locally isomorphic is introduced and could produce counterexamples. Thank you, now I will restrict to the naive problem I come across and make some edits.

Comment: You're right, do you have some countexample of local but not global embedding? By the standard exact sequence of brauer group, two central simple algebras are locally everywhere isomorphic if and only if they are isomorphic.